# can not parse json array from php

Tags: java, android, json

my array returns the following valid json.

```
{"usernames ":["a","b","c"]}
```

In Java I am trying to retrieve the value of the array by the following method. However I fail.

```
JSONArray usernames = json.getJSONArray("usernames");
```

Comment: Are you trying to decode from php or from java?

Comment: try removing the space after usernames

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key ends with a space. try

```
JSONArray usernames = json.getJSONArray("usernames ");
```

EDIT:
It would be better to lose the space in your php script.

Answer (score 2):

remove the space in your code : `"usernames "`  ---> `"usernames"`